# PHP Adicionar records a MYSQLI para todo os USERS

Tags: php

Boas,

Estou tentado que, ao fazer um Registo, esse Registo add em todos os users exemplo.

tabela users

```
  id | username
```

Registo a Adicionar:

```
   id_users | movie_id | movie_name
   user1    |     ex2    |     ex2
   user2    |     ex2    |     ex2
   user3    |     ex2    |     ex2
   user4    |     ex2    |     ex2
```

Estou usando esta forma... Ajudem.

```
              //$uploadOk = false;
          $titulo = $_POST['movie_serie'];
          $direct = $_POST['movie_dir'];

             $db_dir = "libraries/images/upload/".$direct.".jpg"; 

             //$query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO movies (movie_id, movie_name) VALUES ('$db_dir', '$titulo')");  

             $select = "SELECT username FROM users";
             $queryS = mysqli_query($con, $select);

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryS))
                { 
                     $u_array = array('username' => $row['username'], 'movie_id' => $_POST['movie_dir'], 'movie_name' => $_POST['movie_serie']); 

                     $query2 = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO movies_notify (id_users, movie_id, movie_name) 
                     VALUES ($u_array)"); 

                }
```

Comment: Se na tabela `movies_notify` você deve inserir o `id` do usuário, por quê você apenas seleciona o `username`? E você não pode passar um *array* para a instrução SQL, você precisará convertê-lo em *string*.

Answer (score 1):

**Isto é ma pratica!** , devias usar ***[mysqli prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)*** ou **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)**, assim tua aplicação esta vulnerável a vários tipos de ataques!

o problema é que estavas a tentar converter um *array* para **string**..

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryS))
{ 

     $query2 = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO movies_notify (id_users, movie_id, movie_name) VALUES ('".$row['username']."','".$_POST['movie_dir']."','".$_POST['movie_serie']."')"); 

}
```